# How do I float a DIV over the NAV element?

Tags: wordpress, html, css

I have a DIV element with a background image and I am trying to float it over the NAV element that constitutes the menu bar in the 2011 theme. However The DIV always appears underneath the NAV element:

CSS

```
nav#access {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    z-index: 9999;
}

div#logo {
    height: 122px;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 280px;
    background: url(images/mylogo.png);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The DIV is added to the header.php file in the 2011 theme as the 1st element inside the body element.

Comment: can you show an example in http://jsfiddle.net/ for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `<div>` element has a lower `z-index` than your `<nav>` element and thus will always appear "underneath" it.

You just need to specify `div#logo { z-index:10000; }` or higher to bring it in front of the

Comment: Awesome! I have been under the impression that it worked the other way i.e. `z-index: 1` would take precedent over `z-index: 2`...